# Why 'should' is used in "Most unfortunate that it should happen on Christmas day"?

Tags: word-usage, auxiliary-verbs, subjunctives

> "Most unfortunate that it **should** happen on Christmas day."

I'm wondering why '**should**' is used in the sentence. Any difference from: *Most unfortunate that it **happened/happens** on Christmas day.*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modal verb **should** has quite a range of meanings all related in some way to the notion of obligation or necessity, among them that something was destined to happen.

P.S. Compare:

> Why did this **have to happen** on Christmas day, of all days?